# why the first number is being added again and again in my HashSet ? How an HashSet can contain same values?

Tags: java, algorithm

Good morning from Djibouti everybod, i am writing an algorithm who can generate 5 different numbers of
12 characters each one and i have a big problem.

Let me explain :

First, i'm generating 4 different numbers of 3 characters each one and then i make it one number of 12 characters by concatenation. The var containing the number of 12 is last_number

I put that last number in a HashSet table. I'm doing again the same thing to generate another number of 12 and i check if the new number is not in the HashSet table. If, it didn't exist, i add it.

the numbers in the HashSet table has to be different.

Here is the problem, when i print out the values of the HashSet table, all of the 5 numbers are exactly the same. How an HashSet can contain same values ? is it possible ? and why the first number is being added again and again in my HashSet ? and why i can't find the problem to solve ?

Let me show you :

```
public class GenerateNumbers {
    
    static Random rand = new Random();
    static int max;
    static int random_number;
    
    static HashSet<String> different_random_numbers = new HashSet<String>();
    static Iterator<String> iterator;
    static List<String> list_of_final_numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    static HashSet<String> credits_numbers = new HashSet<String>(); 
    
    
    static String last_number;
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        max = 1000;
        
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            String number = generateNumberOf12();
            
            if(credits_numbers.contains(number))
                number = generateNumberOf12();
            else
                credits_numbers.add(number);
            
            iterator = credits_numbers.iterator();
            
            while(iterator.hasNext())
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }
    
    
    //Method generating a single number
    // of 12 characters
    
    public static String generateNumberOf12()
    {   
        HashSet<String> number_generated = generate4NumbersOf3();
        
        list_of_final_numbers.addAll(number_generated);
        
        last_number = list_of_final_numbers.get(0) + list_of_final_numbers.get(1) + list_of_final_numbers.get(2) + list_of_final_numbers.get(3);
        
        return last_number;
    }
    
    
    //Method generating 4 numbers
    // of 3 characters each one
    
    public static HashSet<String> generate4NumbersOf3()
    {
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            random_number = rand.nextInt(max);
            
            String number = String.valueOf(random_number);
            
            if(random_number<100)
            {
                random_number = rand.nextInt(max);
                number = String.valueOf(random_number);
            }
            else if (different_random_numbers.contains(number))
            {
                random_number = rand.nextInt(max);
                number = String.valueOf(random_number);
            }
            else
            {
                different_random_numbers.add(number);
            }
        }
        
        return different_random_numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: you're printing out everything in `credit_numbers` *inside the loop*. I don't think you meant to do that. Move it outside the loop, and step through the code in a debugger.

Comment: You are iterating 5 times over the elements of your `HashSet`, so you are printing the same element multiple times.

Comment: If you successfully add one string to `credit_numbers`, then each time through your `for` loop, you print out that one string. The set `credit_numbers` does not contain duplicates.

Comment: You'd be well advised to get rid of all your static fields. They're unnecessary in this program and they make it confusing to follow. In particular, `generate4NumbersOf3` returns the same set from the static field when it is called multiple times.

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYBODY, I MADE IT !!!! LOVE YOU ALL

Comment: Note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase. Underscores are not used (except for constants).